# Prefix URL-Mapping in JSF causing FileNotFound-Error

Tags: jsf, web.xml, url-pattern

I´m a JSF-Beginner and try to build a small JSF2 webapplication with Spring and Hibernate. My Server of Choice is the JBOSS 7.1 AS.

I´ve encountered an odd Error while trying to map a servlet with a Prefix URL-Pattern. This is the part of the web.xml that declares the Servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapplication/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I now direct my Browser to "localhost:8080/myapp/webapplication/index.xhtml" I get a Mojarra/Facelets generated Error: "/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource".
If I instead configure the URL-Pattern to "*.xhtml" everything is working fine.

I have simply no idea why the Prefix-Pattern isn´t working :/

Greetings

Comment: @Petr: If he didn't, he wouldn't have gotten the error page at all :)

Comment: @BalusC: yeah, that's right. I am really getting tired today:)

Comment: Another thing I discovered:
If I use a welcome-file "/wepapplication/index.xhtml" and than direct the browser to my application suprisingly shows a result... or not. Instead of a FileNotFound-Error I get an empty page. Looking at its sourcecode I can see that it contains the uncompiled JSP-Code. Still, this only occures if I use a Prefix-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :D!

When using a prefix-pattern I thought i had to place my xhtml-files in a folder of that name.
For example I used the pattern "/webapplication/*" so I created a folder "webapplication" and placed my webfiles in there. Now, when directing my Browser to 
"{host}/myapp/webapplication/index.xhtml" I expected the Server to search the files in "{root}/webapplication/index.xhtml". Instead, the Servlet resolved the URL as 
"{host}/myapp/index.xhtml". Because the file isn´t placed there, I get a FileNotFound-Error.

I also learned not to give my resource-folders the same name as my url-patterns.